# Lagom : Access request body while access URL Query Parameters

Tags: java, http, lagom

In Spring framework, we can get the param either from request body or URL Query Parameters:

```
/**
 * test
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String applyService(@RequestParam("param") String param) {
    logger.info(param);
    return "ok";
}
```

how can we do to support both param post way In **Lagom** ?
how to get request info(header/uri/methods/param) in **Lagom** ?

Comment: https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.3.x/java/ServiceDescriptors.html